# AppEngine as WebService and S3 as storage

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-s3

If the client side upload a picture and send to (Google) AppEngine based WebService, can the AppEngine in turn push the file to (Amazon) S3?

Also, can the link returned by S3 be stored on AppEngine, such that when the response to the client side from the AppEngine can have those links.

Is this achievable? or overkill? Has anyone done this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google App Engine and Amazon S3 File Uploads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972895/google-app-engine-and-amazon-s3-file-uploads)

Comment: You could also run this on one of the free micro instances of EC2.  You should get faster transfers speeds between private IPs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, an App Engine app can send files to S3 - but it'll be limited to 1MB in size, as that's the largest payload you can send with a URLFetch request. Consider instead using [browser based uploads](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1) to S3, whereby you can provide the user with a form that allows them to upload the data direct to S3.

If you upload data direct from App Engine, you know the URL of the file, because you specified it. If you use browser based uploads, you can specify a redirect URL for the user's browser, which will notify you once the file was uploaded, containing the URL of the uploaded file.

Comment: what if the client side is actually an app on mobile device?

Comment: Then you can do the same - just make the client implement the form-based upload protocol to S3.