# Uploading a video to google app engine blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm trying to associate a video file to a record with a bunch of properties, but can't seem to allow the user to do everything in one form - name the video, provide description and answer some question, AND upload the file.

Here are the steps I'd like to perform:

1. User is served with a page containing a form with the following fields: Name, Description, File selector.
2. The file gets stored as a blob and the id gets recorded together with name and description.

Does anyone have any examples of doing this I could learn from or a tutorial you could point me to? The one from google only shows uploading the file and getting redirected to it.

Thanks and sorry for a newbish question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code I'm using to upload images and associate them with articles. The toughest bit was getting the article id to get to the upload handler, I solved it by setting the file name as the article id to get around the problem.

```
from lib import urllib2_file
from lib.urllib2_file import UploadFile

# this view serves a task in a queue
def article(request):
       article = Article.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['article'])

       try:
            image = StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(image_url).read())
        except (urllib2.HTTPError, DownloadError):
            article.parsed = True
            article.save()
        else:
            image = UploadFile(image, '.'.join([str(article.id), image_url.rsplit('.', 1)[1][:4]]))
            upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url(reverse('Articles.views.upload'))

            try:
                urllib2.urlopen(upload_url, {'file': image})
            except (DownloadError, RequestTooLargeError):
                pass

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'OK'}))

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        blobs = get_uploads(request, field_name='file', populate_post=True)

        article = Article.objects.get(id=int(blobs[0].filename.split('.')[0]))
        article.media = blobs[0].filename
        article.parsed = True
        article.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Articles.views.upload'))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('meow')

    def upload(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            blobs = get_uploads(request, field_name='file', populate_post=True)

            article = Article.objects.get(id=int(blobs[0].filename.split('.')[0]))
            article.media = blobs[0].filename
            article.parsed = True
            article.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Articles.views.upload'))
        else:
            return HttpResponse('meow')

# this serves the image
def image(request):
    blob = BlobInfo.gql("WHERE filename='%s' LIMIT 1" % request.form.cleaned_data['id'])[0]

    return HttpResponse(BlobReader(blob.key()).read(),
                        content_type=blob.content_type)
```

Also you'll need this http://fabien.seisen.org/python/urllib2_file/

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me a little more context for this (more noob questions) - are you using webapp or django?

Comment: I'm using django-nonrel. Since I'm already used to django that was the easiest way to go about doing this because I didn't have to learn webapp. Also there are some imports and such things missing from the code I pasted, tried to give just the relevant bits :)

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you! Since I lack experience, I just wanted to make sure I could reference some extra docs to better understand it.

Answer (score 5):

http://demofileuploadgae.appspot.com/ - My demo uploader to the blobstore.

My code for the upload: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/source/browse/trunk/DemoUpload/src/org/gonevertical/upload/#upload/server%3Fstate%3Dclosed

Comment: By the way, to clarify for those looking at these examples, this one is JAVA

Comment: well I can upload image file of 3.4 MB using [this](http://demofileuploadgae.appspot.com/) , I doubt it is following the same source that is linked

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it. It is more straight forward than you think. Note the following taken from [Blobstore overview](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html).
*"When the Blobstore rewrites the user's request, the MIME parts of the uploaded files have their bodies emptied, and the blob key is added as a MIME part header. **All other form fields and parts are preserved and passed to the upload handler**."* In the upload handler is where you can do whatever it is you want with the other form fields.

```
    class Topic(db.Model):
        title = db.StringProperty(multiline=False)
        blob = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
        imageurl = db.LinkProperty()

    class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
            self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
            self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
            self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
            <div><label>Title:</label></div>
            <div><textarea name="title" rows="1" cols="25"></textarea></div><input type="submit" 
                name="submit" value="Submit"> </form>""")
            self.response.out.write('<br><br><h2>TOPIC LIST</h2><table border="1"><tr><td>')
            for topic in Topic.all():                
                self.response.out.write('<div><img src="%s=s48"/>' % topic.imageurl)
                self.response.out.write('<div><b>Image URL: </b><i>%s</i></div>' % topic.imageurl)
                self.response.out.write('<div><b>Title: </b><i>%s</i></div>' % topic.title)
            self.response.out.write('</td></tr></table><br>') 
            self.response.out.write('</body></html>')

    class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
        def post(self):
            upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
            blob_info = upload_files[0]
            topic = Topic()
            topic.title = self.request.get("title")
            topic.blob = blob_info.key()
            topic.imageurl = images.get_serving_url(str(blob_info.key()))
            topic.put()        
            self.redirect('/')
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
          [('/', MainHandler),
           ('/upload', UploadHandler),
          ], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```