# Google App Engine (java) no bytearray field when sending blob on deployed server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob

## Problem

Cannot get byte array on deployed server while sending a blob, but it works on the development server.

## Description

While I'm uploading a blob to the server I'm also sending information about the blob to store in the datastore. I do this using a byte array of a serialized class from a Java client as a binary body (see Client side code).

This works perfectly fine in the development server. Getting the byte array also works on the deployed server as long as I don't send it with the blob. I've tried two different methods (shown below) and both works fine except when sending a blob in the deployed server. What I've found is that when I use Apache's FileUpload there are no items to be parsed.

The files I upload are less than 1MB and so is the byte array.

### Get byte array (with Apache's FileUpload)

```
public static byte[] getEntity(HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    if (isMultipart) {
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        try {
            FileItemIterator itemIt = upload.getItemIterator(request);

            while (itemIt.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = itemIt.next();

                if (item.getFieldName().equals(ENTITY_NAME)) {
                    InputStream inputStream = item.openStream();
                    return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException | IOException e) {
            // Log
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

### Get byte array (with MultipartParser)

```
public static byte[] getEntity(HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        MultipartParser multipartParser = new MultipartParser(request, request.getContentLength(), true, true, "UTF-8");
        if (multipartParser != null) {
            Part part;
            while ((part = multipartParser.readNextPart()) != null) {
                if (part.getName().equals(ENTITY_NAME)) {
                    if (part instanceof ParamPart) {
                        return ((ParamPart) part).getValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log
    }
    return null;
}
```

### Client side

```
public static byte[] sendRequest(String uploadUrl, byte[] entity, List<FieldNameFileWrapper> files, List<IOutstreamProgressListener> progressListeners) {
    try {
        MultipartEntityWithProgressBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityWithProgressBuilder.create();
        entityBuilder.addBinaryBody(ENTITY_NAME, entity);

        // Add files
        if (files != null) {
            for (FieldNameFileWrapper fieldNameFile : files) {
                ContentBody contentBody = new FileBody(fieldNameFile.file);
                entityBuilder.addPart(fieldNameFile.fieldName, contentBody);
            }
        }

        if (progressListeners != null) {
            entityBuilder.addProgressListener(progressListeners);
        }


        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);
        httpPost.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());

        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
        byte[] responseEntity = getEntity(httpResponse);
        httpResponse.close();
        return responseEntity;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log
    }

    return null;
}
```

## Previous Research

I've found that the encoding does not work the same on deployed vs. development server, but should this really make any difference if I send a byte array?

## Question

1. What is the error, what have I missed to do?
2. If this does not work on a deployed server, how can I send this information about the blob?

## Update 1

- I have found that the parameter exists if I use `request.getParameterMap()`
- Found an answer in this question ([Google appengine blobstore upload handler processing extra form post parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367757/google-appengine-blobstore-upload-handler-processing-extra-form-post-parameters)). It does exactly as I'm doing, but I don't get any items...

Answer (score 0):

One solution was to send the data as base64 instead of byte array if I'm uploading blobs. Below is the update source code. I will still leave the question open as I'd prefer sending binary data.

### Get byte array (with Apache's FileUpload)

```
public static byte[] getEntity(HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    if (isMultipart) {
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
        try {
            FileItemIterator itemIt = upload.getItemIterator(request);

            while (itemIt.hasNext()) {
                FileItemStream item = itemIt.next();

                if (item.getFieldName().equals(ENTITY_NAME)) {
                    InputStream inputStream = item.openStream();
                    return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
                }
            }

            // If we're here we haven't found the entity, try using base64
            String base64Entity = request.getParameter(ENTITY_NAME);
            if (base64Entity != null) {
                return DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Entity);
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException | IOException e) {
            // Log
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

### Client side

```
public static byte[] sendRequest(String uploadUrl, byte[] entity, List<FieldNameFileWrapper> files, List<IOutstreamProgressListener> progressListeners) {
    try {
        MultipartEntityWithProgressBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityWithProgressBuilder.create();

        // Add files and base64 entity
        if (files != null) {
            for (FieldNameFileWrapper fieldNameFile : files) {
                ContentBody contentBody = new FileBody(fieldNameFile.file);
                entityBuilder.addPart(fieldNameFile.fieldName, contentBody);
            }
            String base64Entity = DatatypeConverter..printBase64Binary(entity);
            entityBuilder.addTextBody(ENTITY_NAME, base64Entity, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        }
        // Add binary entity
        else {
            entityBuilder.addBinaryBody(ENTITY_NAME, entity);
        }

        if (progressListeners != null) {
            entityBuilder.addProgressListener(progressListeners);
        }


        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);
        httpPost.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());

        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Do something with server response...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log
    }

    return null;
}
```