# Uploading multiple large files with django on Google App Engine -- how to do multiple requests

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to figure out how to load multiple large files (like 4K images) to Google Cloud Storage via django using the default admin interface.

For example, I have a model with multiple images:

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    image_1 = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        upload_to="myapp/images"
    )
    image_2 = models.ImageField(
        null=True,
        upload_to="myapp/images"
    )
```

However, if I enter data for this model in the admin interface, this causes an error if I load two large files that go over GAE's 32 MB post limit.

I've tried using `django-gcp` and `BlobField`, but this also causes issues because the temporary uploads overwrite each other before transferring to Google Cloud Storage -- and it doesn't look like this is solvable with `django-gcp` out of the box.

So right now I'm wondering if it's possible to break out upload into multiple POST requests -- that way each one can be a separate ImageField (if under 32MB) or BlobField, and I won't have any issues.

Is there a way I can upload a model in multiple POSTs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google App Engine Large File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842426/google-app-engine-large-file-upload)

Comment: Unfortunately not; I'm using `django-gcp` which I think uses a `BlobStore` under the hood, but the library doesn't seem to allow models with multiple blobs at the moment